# Linux os keeps logging itself off

Tags: logout

I had my laptop wireless card changed a month ago, after that I noticed that the wifi led keep blinking on transmitting data and after a while the OS logged off and started a new session, and kept logging itself off after a while of logging again.

I've tried to use some distros. Like manjaro, fedora and Ubuntu and I faced the same problem.

By the way, I have Windows 10 installed alongside with Linux and this problem is not found, but I hate Windows and want to install Linux again but I cannot fix this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! So what is the distro that you're experiencing this issue with now? Because it's Ubuntu Q&A place. If you have a question concerning other distros you might wanna ask it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: the problem above faced me on ubuntu too

Comment: there can be lots of guesses... you should read your log files when it happens in Ubuntu system they are located at `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/messages` it will tell you what happened last.